# Chrome freeze when refreshing graph with sigma.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sigma.js

I can't understand what is going wrong, sometimes, when i try to render the graph by clicking the "Generate Random Graph" button, my browser CPU jumps to 17% and the browser freezes.

This is the webpage: http://summarify.com/randomideagenerator/
You can find all the source here: https://github.com/alessiop86/display-random-concepts

This is the javascript:

```
      // Self-executing wrapper
(function ($) {

    Backbone.sync = function (method, model, success, error) {
        success();
    }

    /* Model */
    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            concept: 'description',
            displayChoice: 'random'
        }
    });

    var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item
    });

    /* End of model */

    /* Views */

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'tr',

        events: {
            'click button.delete': 'remove',
            'change input[type=text]': 'conceptChanged',
            'click input[type=radio]': 'displayChoiceChanged'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'remove','conceptChanged','displayChoiceChanged'); 
            this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);            
        },
        conceptChanged:function(evt) {

           var value = $(evt.currentTarget).val();
            this.model.set('concept',value)

        },

        displayChoiceChanged:function(evt) {
            var value = $(evt.currentTarget).val();
            this.model.set('displayChoice',value)
        },

        render: function () {

            //workaround to access @ this.model from the anonymous inner function
            //making it a closure for the free variable model
            var model = this.model

            //workaround because .html() is not working with <tr>
            $(this.el).each(function(){                    

              jQuery(this)[0].innerHTML = '<tr><td>' + '<div class="form-group">' + '<div class="form-control-wrapper"><input value="' + model.get('concept') + '" class="form-control concept"  type="text"><span class="material-input"></span></div>' + '</div>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<div class="radio radio-primary">' + '<label>' + '<input type="radio" value="mandatory">' + '<span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>' + '</label>' + '</div>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<div class="radio radio-primary">' + '<label>' + '<input type="radio" value="random" checked="checked">' + '<span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>' + '</label>' + '</div>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<div class="radio radio-primary">' + '<label>' + '<input type="radio" value="disabled" >' + '<span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>' + '</label>' + '</div>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<button class="btn btn-primary delete" type="button">Remove</button>' + '</td></tr>';
    });
            return this; 
        },

        unrender: function () {
            $(this.el).remove();
        },

        remove: function () {
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });

    /*Main view (List) */
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('div#left'), 

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem'); 

            this.collection = new List();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);


            /* Remove this block below, just for showcase purpose */
            var testModel = getTestModel();
            for (var i=0;i<testModel.length;i++) {                
                var item = new Item();
                item.set(testModel[i]);
                this.collection.add(item);
            }
            /* End of test showcase block */


            this.render(); //self-rendering view
        },

        events: {
            'click button#add': 'addItem',
            'click button#random': 'displayRandom'
        },

        appendItem: function (item) {
            var itemView = new ItemView({
                model: item
            });
            $('tbody', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
        },

        render: function () {

            var self = this;

            $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add item</button>");

            $(this.el).append("&nbsp;<button id='random'>Generate random graph</button>");

            $(this.el).append("<table class=\"table table-striped table-hover \">" 
                                + "<thead>"
                                + "<tr>" 
                                + "<th>Concept</th>" 
                                + "<th>Mandatory</th>" 
                                + "<th>Random</th>"
                                + "<th>Disabled</th>" 
                                + "<th>Remove</th>"
                                + "</tr>"
                                + "</thead>"
                                +"<tbody></tbody>"
                                +"</table>");

            this.collection.each(function (item) { 
                self.appendItem(item);
            }, this);
        }


        ,
        addItem: function () {

            var item = new Item();
            item.set({
                concept: prompt("Write concept:"),
                displayChoice : "random",
            });
            this.collection.add(item);
        },




        displayRandom: function() {

            displayRandomGraph(this.collection.models);
        }


    });

    /* end of Views */

    //Instantiate main app view.
    var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);

/* End of Backbone.js app */

/* Start of Graph generation code */

var  g2 = {
  "nodes": [],
  "edges": []
};

var s2 =  new sigma(  {
      renderers: [ {
            container: document.getElementById('innerRightCanvas'),
            type:'canvas'   
        } ],
        settings: {
            sideMargin:80,
            labelThreshold:1,
            mouseEnabled:false,
            enableHovering: false,
            autoRescale: false,
            autoResize:false,
            rescaleIgnoreSize: false

        }, graph: g2

    });
//console.log(s2);

/**
Grap
*/
function displayRandomGraph(concepts) {

    //disable multiple clicks
    //$("#random").prop('disabled', true);
    //setTimeout(function() {  $("#random").prop('disabled', false); }, 500);

    s2.graph.clear();

    //nodes
    for (var i=0; i < concepts.length; i++) {                

        //Compute display choice
        if (concepts[i].get("displayChoice") == "disabled" || ( concepts[i].get("displayChoice") == "random" && Math.random() < 0.5) )
            continue;


        var id = "n" + s2.graph.nodes().length;
        var concept = { 
            "id" : id,
            "label" : concepts[i].get('concept'),
            "x" : Math.round(200 * (0.5 - Math.random())), 
            "y" : Math.round(200 * (0.5 - Math.random())), 
            'size': Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 2,
            'color': 'rgb('+Math.round(Math.random()*256)+','+  Math.round(Math.random()*256)+','+ Math.round(Math.random()*256)+')'
            }

            s2.graph.addNode(concept)
    }

    //edges    
    for (var i=0; i < s2.graph.nodes().length; i++) {

        var edgesForCurrentNode = Math.round(Math.pow(Math.random(),2) * 3);

        for (var j=0; j<edgesForCurrentNode;j++) {

            var start = s2.graph.nodes()[i].id
            var end = start;

            //edges allowed only between different nodes
            while (end == start) {            
                end = "n" + Math.round(Math.random()*(s2.graph.nodes().length -1));
            }

            var edge = {
              "id": "e" + s2.graph.edges().length,
              "source": start,
              "target": end
            };


            s2.graph.addEdge(edge)
        }

    }

    //console.log("NODES");console.log(s2.graph.nodes());
    //console.log("EDGES");console.log(s2.graph.edges());
    s2.refresh()

}

/* End of Graph generation code */


/**
test showcase
*/
function getTestModel() {

   var testCollection = [];
   for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        var item = {
            concept: "Concept " + i,
            displayChoice: "random",
        };
        testCollection.push(item);
    }
    return testCollection;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I am having no freezing issues with chrome.

Comment: @Grimbode I am using chrome, try to click "Generate Random Graph" several times in a row and the freezing issue should occure. Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean. I had to click a lot before that problem occured.

Comment: A "while" loop is freezing your main browser thread (backbone-app.js: line 236), you should consider running displayRandomGraph function asynchronously or in a new thread (or use the new HTML5 web workers)

Comment: @vzamanillo that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs when there is only one node in the graph and `edgesForCurrentNode` is bigger than zero, and you try to connect an egde between two nodes:

```
while (end == start) {            
                end = "n" + Math.round(Math.random()*(s2.graph.nodes().length -1));
 }
```

Since there is only one node, end will be "n0" and the while loop will not end.

If there is only one node, you can skip the edges part and refresh the graph:

```
if (s2.graph.nodes().length > 1) {
    //edges    
    for (var i=0; i < s2.graph.nodes().length; i++) {

        var edgesForCurrentNode = Math.round(Math.pow(Math.random(),2) * 3);

        for (var j=0; j<edgesForCurrentNode;j++) {

            var start = s2.graph.nodes()[i].id
            var end = start;

            //edges allowed only between different nodes
            while (end == start) {            
                end = "n" + Math.round(Math.random()*(s2.graph.nodes().length -1));
            }

            var edge = {
              "id": "e" + s2.graph.edges().length,
              "source": start,
              "target": end
            };


            s2.graph.addEdge(edge)
        }

    }
}
```